# hundreds sleeps in MySQL / MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, mariasql

I have hundreds of sleeping connections in my MariaDB. Is there a way to find out which php script this caused?

Does this low MariaDB down?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is this the list created by `show processlist;`?

Comment: @NateStone yes it is. Ive hided only the databases users

Comment: netstat might give you a clue, maybe even tcpdump

Comment: Shouldn't there bei the PID displayed behind localhost? If I do this comand on my machine it looks like `localhost:61123, localhost:611124,.....` where the number is the PID of the process. If this number is displayed you could echo out the php-command `getmypid()` (which displays the process ID of the process computing this php-script) in your scripts and compare it to the process numbers behind localhost (`localhost:61123`). And then you have the scripts causing this sleeping processes.

Comment: oh no. Forget about my suggest. I messed up. It's not the Process ID its the port. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

It could be some form of "connection pooling" that is leaving lots of connections open.

What is your client?  If it is Apache, decrease MaxClients to, say, 10.

Another approach... Decrease `max_connections` (in mysqld) to, say 20.  Then look for errors in your client when they try to exceed that.